# Need to create CFG that requires sum of other letters

Tags: finite-automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I have a homework assignment that requires me to create CFG $G$ for

$$L = \{a^i b^{i+j+k} c^j d^k\}$$

so that it can accept words like ab, aaabbbbd, abbbcd, but it should not accept abba, aabbbbbc, or abc since the number of b must be the number of a+c+d.

I need CFG of L(G)

- I tried using chatgpt but the answers are not correct as I cross checked them with both gpt and myself.
- I tried to cross check [this pdf](https://staffwww.dcs.shef.ac.uk/people/J.Marshall/alc/studyguides/Selected_Solutions_2.pdf) but they are not as complex as my question.
- There is also a [solution on chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-finite-strings-alphabet-b-c-d--power-operation-represents-string-repetition-examp-q98055624?auth_provider=oa&nruuid=16a2b008)  I can't see the whole solution as I don't have a subscription, but the final solution is also wrong as I checked it with both chatgpt and myself.
- Also researched multiple sources but did not found the answer.

The best one i came up with this grammer but it doesn't feel right since it does not have corelation between b c and d.

```
1. attempt: 

S → AB 
A → aAb | ε
B -> bCEdD
C -> bB | ε
D -> dD | ε
E -> bEc | ε

2. attempt : 

S → AB 
A → aA | ε
B → bBC 
C → cC | Cd | ε 
D → dD | ε
```

Is it possible to do it with cfg and how?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: I have already answered this question in the "Asnwers" section. I have problems understanding the accepted words, even after reading the proof of correctness @D.W.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [nesting structure](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/26159/4287) of the language to obtain a context-free grammar.

$a^i\, b^{i+j+k}\, c^j d^k = a^i b^i\, b^k b^j c^j d^k $

We can see that the language is the concatenation of
strings of the form
$a^i\, b^i $
and strings of the form
$b^{j+k}\, c^j d^k$
which each separately form context-free languages.

Comment: The part I don't understand is when I use a cfg like :

- S → ABcd
- A → aAb | ε
- B → bBc | ε
- C → cCd | ε

seems to be correct and also produces what I'm asking for, but it also accepts words like "abba, aabbbbc or abc" which I want to use specifically and only for the words I'm describing, so if the language doesn't have that, that's the part I don't understand

Comment: Respect the nesting structure. Generate "bc"-pairs inside the "bd"-pairs.

Comment: I also add this cfg to the main question but here's what i did : S → AB  ---- A → aAb | ε ---- B -> bCEdD ---- C -> bB | ε ---- D -> dD | ε ---- E -> bEc | ε. I can't solve that point i don't know how to add bc in bd because there's also an bcd combination that i need to make recursive.

Answer (score 0):

$S\rightarrow AD$
$A\rightarrow aAb,\varepsilon$
$D\rightarrow bDd, C$
$C\rightarrow bCc, \varepsilon$.

In this solution I divided the word into a prefix of $a^ib^i$ and a suffix of $b^{j+k}c^jd^k$. The latter part is generated by building $b^kCd^k$ and then replacing $C$ with $b^jc^j$.

Comment: Is the " , " the same as the " | " or does this symbol have a different purpose?

Comment: yes it is the same, I just mean different choices of the right side.